# If I want to use an infinitive as an adverb in the sentence then I can use an infinitive with any verb as an adverb?

Tags: american-english, british-english, infinitives, indian-english, infinitive-phrases

If I want to use an infinitive as an adverb in the sentence then can I use it with any verb or specific verb?

suppose I want to say " I went there to drive the car" so here to drive the car is an adverb talking about the " went" verb so Can I use an infinitive as an adverb with any verbs? like " went"

Comment: Study the difference between *adverbs* **drivingly** (in the metaphorical sense) and *infinitives* (purpose) **to drive**. Your example also makes little logical sense, (you went somewhere because you wanted to drive),  did you get there on foot?  Next time try to come up with a better example.

Comment: Personally, the original question before you deleted most of the detail did a better job of explaining your problem. The post still needed editing but from my point of view I understood what you were trying to say.

Comment: These are called to-infinitives and state the purpose of the main idea. I went there to [for the purpose of driving the car] drive the car.

Answer (score 7):

> *I went there* [*to drive the car*].

When you say 'adverb', I think you mean adjunct. An adverb is a single word like "clearly", "very" "almost" and the like.

The expression "to drive the car" is an infinitival **clause** functioning as a purpose adjunct: it gives the purpose of your going there.

There are a great many verbs that are performed for a particular purpose, and thus can take a purpose adjunct.

Answer (score 4):

In the example,  "to drive the car" gives the *purpose*.  It doesn't describe how you went there, it gives the reason for you to go there.  It doesn't mean "I went there by car".

> I went to the racetrack to drive the race car. It is illegal to drive it on the normal road, so I went by train.

You can use infinitives in clauses with any verb. But it might not always be sensible.